# Assigning variables from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe:

df:

```
Name    Value
A       30
B       40
C       50
```

How can i read this dataframe so that i can use these values as variables for my code?

Like:

```
A=30
B=40
C=50
```

I was trying something on these lines:

```
for n in range(len(df)):
    A = df.at[n, "A"]
    B = df.at[n, "B"]
    C = df.at[n, "C"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simliest is create `Series` by index from `Name` column by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)and then select by labels by [`Series.at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html) or [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
s = df.set_index('Name')['Value']
print (s)
Name
A    30
B    40
C    50
Name: Value, dtype: int64

A = s.at["A"]
B = s.at["B"]
C = s.at["C"]

print (A,B,C)
30 40 50
```

Or if want filter by columns names it is possible by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), but output is Series, so for first value use [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
A = df.at[df['Name'].eq("A"), 'Value'].iat[0]
B = df.at[df['Name'].eq("B"), 'Value'].iat[0]
C = df.at[df['Name'].eq("C"), 'Value'].iat[0]
```